# Como analisar corretamente as saídas das Tabelas Verdade das Identidades Booleanas?

Tags: tabela-verdade, sistemas-digitais

Eu consigo elaborar as tabelas verdade de acordo  com os postulados, porém eu não consigo ter a visão de análise sob a saída da tabela verdade para afirmar que aquela resposta é realmente a tal.

Por exemplo, temos os seguintes postulados abaixo e suas respectivas tabelas verdade:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como eu posso afirmar a partir das saídas das tabelas verdades que a tal resposta é aquela mesma?**

Comment: Da um exemplo do que você quer afirmar. 
Por exemplo, sendo A = 1. Se A + 0 então A pois  1 ou 0 é 1.

Comment: @thiagodias eu quero afirmar por exemplo: porque A+0 = A, porém afirmando isto através das saídas das tabelas verdade das mesmas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em uma tabela verdade devem ser colocadas linhas contendo todas as combinações possíveis de valores para cada uma das variáveis "de entrada". Como exemplo, vamos montar a tabela verdade para a proposição `A + B = A`:

```
A | B | A + B |A + B = A 
0 | 0 | 0     |1
1 | 0 | 1     |1
0 | 0 | 0     |1
0 | 1 | 1     |0
```

Neste exemplo, a quarta linha, contendo a combinação de entrada `A = 0` e `B = 1`, resulta na saída `0` (a saída é a coluna `A + B = A`). Ou seja, a proposição falha para esta entrada e portanto não pode ser verdadeira.

Perceba que uma proposição só é verdadeira se ao construir a tabela com todas as combinações possíveis de valores para as variáveis de entrada, nenhuma saída resultar em falha.

Creio que a sua dificuldade em entender a utilidade das tabelas como meio de prova é porque todas as expressões que você testou são expressões verdadeiras e muito simples, com apenas uma variável livre.

Por exemplo, imagine uma expressão com 3 variáveis livres e que você realmente não faça ideia se é falsa ou verdadeira. Um exemplo:

```
(A+B)+C.(B+(C+A)) = C+B
```

A tabela dessa expressão terá 8 linhas (2^3=8, onde 3 é o número de variáveis). O número de colunas vai depender do grau de detalhamento que você vai querer para cada passo da análise, mas provavelmente serão várias colunas.

Bem, acho que é isso. No seu caso as expressões são tão simples que a tabela passa a ser mera constatação. Talvez, utilizar uma coluna a mais torne a conclusão mais explícita (exemplo abaixo), mas o grande valor das tabelas você vai perceber em expressões mais complexas e na aplicação delas em problemas práticos.

```
A | B | A + 0 |A + 0 = A 
0 | 0 | 0     |1
1 | 0 | 1     |1
```

Comment: Considero mais comum o uso das tabelas para aplicações do que para formalização. Por exemplo, podemos imaginar um sistema digital que foi concebido a partir de uma série de ideias, divididas em várias etapas. Depois, com este sistema pronto, o que se deseja é correlacionar a entrada com a saída, tornando todas aquelas etapas uma caixa preta, só que uma caixa preta otimizada. A pergunta vira: qual a maneira mais simples de fazer esta entrada gerar aquela saída, não me importa como.